# Detecting whether a WKWebView has blanked

Tags: swift, ios8, wkwebview

I am building a simple iOS app using SWIFT. It loads a single page app in WKWebView in the main view full screen. Clicking advertisement would open another WKWebView in a new scene presented modally. However, if I click several pages in the new scene and go back to the main view, the main view has a 50% chance to go blank.

When the main view goes blank, it disappears from the Safari inspector and webView.reload() doesn't work. But loadHTMLString works. So I can do something like this:

```
1. override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
2.     super.viewWillAppear(false)
3.     if pageStatus == .BackFromAdScene {
4.         if webView is Blank {
5.              loadFromLocal()
6.         }
7.     }
8. }
```

I'm curious about what is the simplest way to detect whether a WKWebView is Blank? In other words, how should I write line 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Objective-c I did it with this trick:

```
    [self.webView evaluateJavaScript:@"document.querySelector('body').innerHTML" completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error) {
       if (!result || ([result isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [((NSString *)result) length] == 0)) {
       // reload your page
    }];
```

Answer (score 4):

user3437673's answer is correct. Here's the SWIFT code for people like me, who came to iOS development just recently.

```
       self.webView?.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelector('body').innerHTML") { (result, error) in
            if error != nil {
                // the main web view has turned blank
                // do something like reload the page
            }
        }
```

Comment: Correct also for Swift.